# Trying loop the list so it print out each even number

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to find a way to get applescript to display odd and even number.

These numbers are even 4
These numbers are even 6
These numbers are even 8
These numbers are even 10

These numbers are odd 3

These numbers are odd 5

These numbers are odd 7

These numbers are odd 9

I tried looking it up but I don't really understand applescript that well.

```
set numberList to {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
repeat with i in numberList
  repeat while i mod 2 = 0
    display dialog "These numbers are even " & i
  end repeat
end repeat

set numberList to {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
repeat with numberList in numberList
  repeat while numberList mod 2 = 1
    display dialog "These numbers are odd " & numberList
  end repeat
end repeat
```

No errors. Just stuck in a infinite loop.
Just display: These numbers are even 4 over and over again

Answer (score 0):

The `repeat with X in Y` form steps through the Y list, with the loop variable X containing the current item in the list.  Your snippets are using an additional repeat loop that will continue while some condition is met, but since the comparison variable is not changing inside the inner loop, once the test is true the repeat will never end.

You just need to replace the inner repeat loop with a plain `if ... then` comparison, for example:

```
set numberList to {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
repeat with i in numberList
  if i mod 2 = 0 then
    display dialog "This number is even: " & i
  end if
end repeat

set numberList to {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
repeat with i in numberList
  if i mod 2 = 1 then
    display dialog "This number is odd: " & i
  end if
end repeat
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I see my errors now. But before I was using a return command and it will only return the first value in my list.

Comment: The `return` command does just that - it returns from the script or handler (optionally with a value), ending it.  If you want to return several values you will need to do something like create a list, add items to the list, then return the list when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace each *inner* repeat loop, i.e. the `while` loops, with an `if...then` conditional test clause, e.g.:

```
set numberList to {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

repeat with i in numberList
    if i mod 2 = 0 then display dialog "This number is even: " & i
end repeat
```

The `if...then` clause can be extended to include an `else` block that will get executed whenever the condition being tested fails.  This allows your two repeat loops to be combined into one, iterating only once through your list and giving you the outcome for both odds and evens in one go:

```
set numberList to {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

repeat with i in numberList
    if i mod 2 = 0 then
        -- This block will only run if the number is even
        display dialog "This number is even: " & i
    else 
        -- This block will only run if the number is not even
        display dialog "This number is odd: " & i
    end if
end repeat
```